# Can't resolve KeyError in Pandas

Tags: machine-learning, gpt-2, fine-tuning

I have written this code to fine-tune gpt2 on a dataset imported from HuggingFace:

```
from transformers import Trainer, TrainingArguments, GPT2LMHeadModel, GPT2Tokenizer
model_name = "gpt2"
tokenizer = GPT2Tokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
model = GPT2LMHeadModel.from_pretrained(model_name)

training_args = TrainingArguments(
output_dir="./output",
num_train_epochs=3,
per_device_train_batch_size=8,
logging_dir="./logs",
)

trainer = Trainer(
model=model,
args=training_args,
train_dataset=train,
tokenizer=tokenizer,
)
trainer.train()`
```

When I run this, I am getting KeyError:9198 though 9198 is included in dataframe of my dataset (I checked it twice)

This is the error I have encountered:
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
3801             try:
-> 3802                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
3803             except KeyError as err:

11 frames
pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 9198

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
3802                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
3803             except KeyError as err:
-> 3804                 raise KeyError(key) from err
3805             except TypeError:
3806                 # If we have a listlike key, _check_indexing_error will raise

KeyError: 9198